# The localization of a ring at a maximal ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, local-rings

I am working on the following problem:

If $R$ is a local ring whose maximal ideal is denoted $\mathfrak{p}$ then show that $R \cong R_\mathfrak{p}$.

$R_\mathfrak{p} := \{\frac{r}{u} : r\in R, u\in R\setminus\mathfrak{p}\}/\sim$ where $\frac{r}{u} \sim \frac{r'}{u'}$ if $\exists \tilde{u}\in R\setminus\mathfrak{p}$ such that $\tilde{u}(ru' - r'u) = 0$.

So far I have shown that any element $x \in R\setminus\mathfrak{p}$ must be a unit. Then i thought about trying to show that the homomorphism $\phi:R\to R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a bijection however I cannot see how to show either injectivity or surjectivity. For the surjective case I thought perhaps one could show that every element $\frac{r}{u} \in R_\mathfrak{p}$ is equivalent to $\frac{r}{1} \in R_\mathfrak{p}$ but this does not seem to work.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $r/u$ will not be equivalent to $r/1$ but to $rx/1$ where $x$ is the inverse of $r$ (which you have shown to exist).

Comment: Do you mean $x$ is the inverse of $u$? And if you do, does this actually help show surjectivity? Since now $r$/$u$ is only equivalent to elements dependent on our choice of $u$.

Comment: Yes, obviously the element $r/u$ depends on which $u$ we pick, but this is fine. That it is equivalent to an element of the form $y/1$ precisely means that the usual homomorphism is surjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define $f: R \longrightarrow R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as $f(x) = \frac{x}{1}$.

This is a well defined ring homomorphism.

Injectivity: Suppose $\frac{x}{1} = 0 = \frac{0}{1}$. Then there exist $u \in R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ such that $u(x - 0) = 0$. But $u$ is invertible, so $x = 0$.

Surjectivity: for all $\frac{x}{y} \in R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ we have $y\in R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$, so $y$ is invertible. Since $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{xy^{-1}}{1}$, the we have that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: More generally this shows $S^{-1}R \cong R$ if $S$ is a subgroup of the units of $R$.